# strange string format percent c# output

Tags: c#, string-formatting

does anybody have an idea why following code outputs *1000%* for *RebatePercent=10* :

```
return RebatePercent > 0 ? $"{RebatePercent.ToString("0%")}" : "-";
```

I didn't find anything to output 10%

thx

Comment: `%` - *Multiplies a number by **100** and inserts a localized percentage symbol in the result string.*

Comment: so the solution is to divide RebatePercent by 100 or to use another format?

Comment: You Can Use string.Format instead of ToString() like:-string.Format("Percentage is {0:0.0%}", ratio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use as:

```
RebatePercent > 0 ? String.Format("{0}%", RebatePercent) : "-";
```

and in C#6:

```
RebatePercent > 0 ? $"{RebatePercent}%" : "-";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the use of string interpolation then you can just:

```
return RebatePercent > 0 ? $"{RebatePercent.ToString()}%" : "-";
```